# Center content vertically inside flex children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using Flexbox I have this simple example..

```css
.container {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
   height:100vh;
}

.box1{height:100%;background:green;}
.box2{height:100%;background:red;}
.box3{height:100%;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        This is some dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0020/66t">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y07xr5q3/1/

I would like the content of each div to be vertically centered, is this something that should be done using standard CSS techniques or is there a flex specific way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Make your child elements flex containers with `display: flex;`.
2. Set their vertical alignment with `align-items: center`.

**Necessary CSS:**

```
div.box {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.box {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.box1{height:100%;background:green;}
.box2{height:100%;background:red;}
.box3{height:100%;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
        This is some dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0020/66t">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, makes sense now!

Comment: Any idea why an added button would be on the same line as the text?  https://jsfiddle.net/y07xr5q3/2/

Comment: @fightstarr20 By default flex children are placed in a row. Change this behavior by explicitly adding `flex-direction: column` if you wants elements in vertical order. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/y07xr5q3/3/)

Comment: But then the contents are no longer vertically aligned

Comment: @fightstarr20 Sorry forgot add `justify-content: center` Check updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/y07xr5q3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
.box1{height:100%;background:green;}
.box2{height:100%;background:red;}
.box3{height:100%;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        This is some dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0020/66t">
    </div>
</div>
```

Live demo https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/y07xr5q3/4/